# Different behaviour of `isolation: isolate` when div is inside table

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have span with text:

```
<span id="parent">
  text
<span>
```

Then I add to this span another absolutely positioned `<span>` with `z-index: -1` and `background-color: green`:

```css
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<span id="parent">
  text
  <span id="child"></span>
</span>
```

So, there is green rect behind text. Then I add `isolation: isolate` to `#parent` span, now it has own stacking context. Then I put `#parent` span inside table with red background:

```css
table {
  background: red;
}

#parent {
  isolation: isolate;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="parent">
          text
          <span id="child"></span>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In Chrome 61 `#child` span is below table, so both red and green colors are visible:

[image: chrome screenshot]

In Firefox 55 `#child` span is above table, so only green color is visible:

[image: firefox screenshot]

Which browser is correct and why?

Comment: I'd say Firefox is correct because #child participates in the stacking context established by #parent via isolation: isolate. In Chrome, #child is effectively bleeding out of #parent, into the root stacking context (where the table resides) - as though isolation: isolate never causes #parent to establish a stacking context.

Comment: @BoltClock, ok, thanks. I [submit issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=772648) about it